# How to detect availability of the Web Share Target API?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I want to teach the user a different flow if the [Web Share Target API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/12/web-share-target) is available. Is there a way to detect if it's available?

Comment: If you go to that page in Firefox, it'll say `navigator.share is not supported in this browser, try sharing from another app instead.`, so presumably yes. Look for the line `if ('share' in navigator) {` in the source.

Comment: @ceejayoz this detects if the Web Share API is available. I'm trying to find out if the Web Share Target API is available.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Web Share Target spec](https://w3c.github.io/web-share-target/) (draft version Dec. 22, 2022), I don't see any provision for the website to detect whether the feature is supported by the current browser.

At this time, the Web Share Target API appears to be only supported by browsers implementing the WebAPK technology. That means the Chrome™-brand browser on Android. It's not supported by Chromium-based browsers, by Firefox, or by any browser on any other OS to my knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (navigator.share === undefined) {
    console.log('Error: Unsupported  feature: navigator.share');
}
```

```js
if (navigator.share === undefined) {
   alert('Error: Unsupported  feature: navigator.share');
}
```

Comment: This detects if the Web Share API is available. I'm trying to find out if the Web Share Target API is available.